# Connect calendar invite response to custom field?

Tags: integration, campaign, calendar, sync, nonprofit-starter-pack

Is there an integration to connect calendar invite status (perhaps with Outlook) to a Salesforce field?

I'm setting up Volunteers for Salesforce and am manually creating Outlook calendar invites for volunteer shifts and then going back and manually changing the shift status field to "confirmed" based on whether or not the volunteer accepted the invite.

Is there any way to automate either of these steps: sending calendar invites or marking the status?

Answer (score 0):

This trail on Trailhead should cover this. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/nonprofit_volunteer